# For audit logging, which technique is the best?

Tags: mysql, logging, redis, elastic-stack, audit

I need to choose a technique to store and retrieve the auditing logs(when something was added, deleted, modified, etc). The scenario is : the logs may be increased by 10 million per day and will be retrieved by some key words. 
So my question is:

- which techique should I use, such as **ELK**(Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana ) or **MySQL** or **Redis** or something better and why.

Answer (score 3):

**ELK** is kind of the standard option for this. It's reliable, has great and *fast* keyword searching across millions of records, and can scale fairly linearly.

**MySQL** would be an OK secondary choice, but depending on the time horizon you'll need to keep, you'll eventually run into a scaling issue either in terms of space or search ability (within reasonable time frame) without sharding. Sharding would take care of a lot of those issues, but it's going to likely be more manual and more painful than something like ELK which is very easy to set up to index/shard by date.

**Redis** Wouldn't be a very good choice for this. All redis data *must* fit in memory, which limits the amount of log data you can keep drastically. Key/value is also not a good fit for log-structured data, especially wrt its searchability, which in redis would be basically none.

If you were to outgrow ELK, the next best option would probably be something like HDFS + Hadoop/Spark searching (or S3+EMR if you're in AWS-land), but at 10 million a day ELK should last a good while (depending on the time horizon). Just as an example I currently work with a 10-node ELK cluster that handles about a billion log items per day and we keep two weeks worth of history.

---

EDIT:

For audit logging specifically like you're looking for, for added reliability, it may be useful to have something like a kafka stream to write into as a layer between your application and ELK. This will get around some potentially weird/crappy behavior one might run into relying on log file shipping, and gets you an indefinite, replayable stream of all changes.

Comment: A simple method to add an audit log is to use another thread to do that (such as spring @Async) But with the logs increasing, the cost of manaing threads is large. So message quesue (such as kafka) is a nice suggestion. I also wonder is there any method of keeping audit logs in the application without code intrusion ?  As there will exist large amount of duplicated code for keeping logs in the application

Comment: That depends a good bit on your application architecture. If your db access is cleanly separated in your code and entities have their own managing class/service one could envision a generic entity logger which data management classes could inherent for their operations and have this happen automatically. I'm not super familiar with Spring which I suppose is what you're working with, so I don't necessarily have a very specific suggestion there.